# ref issues due to React Portals and componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**
I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement a Portal component that wraps React's native portal utility. The component would simply handle creating the portal's root element, safely inserting it into the DOM, rendering any of the component's children into it, and then safely removing it again from the DOM as the component is unmounting.

**The Problem:**
React strongly advises against side effects (like manipulating the DOM) outside of React's safe life cycle methods (componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, etc...) since that has the potential to cause problems (memory leaks, stale nodes, etc...). In React's examples of how to use Portals, they mount the portal's root element into the DOM tree on componentDidMount, but that seems to be causing other problems.

**Issue number 1:**
If the Portal component 'portals' it's children into the created root element during it's render method, but waits until it's componentDidMount method fires before appending that root element into the DOM tree, then any of the portal's children which need access to the DOM during their own componentDidMount life cycle methods will have issues, since at that point in time they will be mounted to a detached node.
This [issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/272) was later addressed in React's docs which recommend setting a 'mounted' property to true on the Portal component's state once the Portal component had finished mounting and successfully appended the portals root element to the DOM tree. Then in the render, you could hold off on rendering any of the Portal's children until that mounted property was set to true, as this would guarantee that all of those children would be rendered into the actual DOM tree before their own respective componentDidMount life cycle methods would fire off. Great. But this leads us to...

**Issue number 2:**
If your Portal component holds off on rendering any of it's children until after it itself has mounted, then any of the componentDidMount life cycle methods of it's ancestors will also fire off prior to any of those children being mounted. So any of the Portal component's ancestors that need access to refs on any of those children during their own componentDidMount life cycle methods will have issues. I haven't figured out a good way to get around this one yet.

**Question:**
Is there a clean way to safely implement a portal component so that it's children will have access to the DOM during their componentDidMount life cycle methods, while also allowing the portal component's ancestors to have access to refs on those children during their own respective componentDidMount life cycle methods?

**Reference Code:**

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export default class Portal extends Component {

    static propTypes = {

        /** This component uses Portals to dynamically render it's contents into
        *   whatever DOM Node contains the **id** supplied by this prop
        *   ('portal-root' by default). If a DOM Node cannot be found with the
        *   specified **id** then this component will create one and append it
        *   to the 'Document.Body'. */
        rootId: PropTypes.string

    };

    static defaultProps = {
        rootId: 'portal-root'
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { mounted: false };
        this.portal = document.createElement('div');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setRoot();
        this.setState({ mounted: true });
    }

    componentDidUpdate( prevProps, prevState ) {
        if( this.props.rootId !== prevProps.rootId ) this.setRoot();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if( this.root ) {
            this.root.removeChild(this.portal);
            if( !this.root.hasChildNodes() ) this.root.parentNode.removeChild(this.root);
        }
    }

    render() {

        this.portal.className = this.props.className ? `${this.props.className} Portal` : 'Portal';

        return this.state.mounted && ReactDOM.createPortal(
            this.props.children,
            this.portal,
        );
    }

    setRoot = () => {

        this.prevRoot = this.root;
        this.root = document.getElementById(this.props.rootId);

        if(!this.root) {
            this.root = document.createElement('main');
            this.root.id = this.props.rootId;
            document.body.appendChild(this.root);
        }

        this.root.appendChild(this.portal);

        if( this.prevRoot && !this.prevRoot.hasChildNodes() ) {
            this.prevRoot.parentNode.removeChild(this.prevRoot);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `constructor` is a valid lifecycle method in which you can perform side effects.  There's no reason you can't create/attach the root element in the constructor:

```
class Portal extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super();
     const root = document.findElementById(props.rootId);
     this.portal = document.createElement('div');
     root.appendChild(portal);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.portal.parent.removeChild(this.portal);
  }

  render() {
     ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.portal);
  }

  // TODO: add your logic to support changing rootId if you *really* need it
}
```

Comment: Well I could be mistaken, and please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think React's docs mention somewhere that componentWillUnmount is only guaranteed to fire if componentDidMount was fired previously. Meaning that it's entirely possible for a component to get removed prior to it ever completing it's mounting cycle, and in such cases there is no guarantee that componentWillUnmount will ever fire. If that's the case, then any dom nodes added in the constructor aren't guaranteed to get cleaned up if the component is removed prior to it it's mounting, leaving the possibility of stale nodes.

Comment: In the issue I linked above, bvaughn from React's core team mentioned the following:
"Side effects (like modifying the DOM) are only safe in `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` methods." I'm assuming that excludes the constructor.

If there is no other solution though, that will likely be the path I end up taking. Though it would come as a surprise to me if only clean solution was considered an unsafe one.

Comment: True. You may have to pick your poison.

Comment: @Spencer You're right, thanks, now [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) explicitly suggest a workaround: *"add state and only render the children when inserted in the DOM tree"*. So my solution was using `this.setState({ mounted: true })` in `componentDidMount`, and conditional rendering inside the portal using that flag in the state.

Comment: @lorenzo-s That's the approach I take in my Reference code above. Unless something has changed over the last two years, that will lead to a different problem that I tried to explain under the Issue 2 header above. As an example let's say you have a component that renders an input element and uses a ref to that input to give it focus during it's own componentDidMount lifecycle method. Normally that would work fine, but if you then wrap that input with the portal component I referenced above you'll run into an issue, because... (continued)

Comment: (continued)...  the Parent's componentDidMount lifecycle method will fire off before the input element actually get's rendered, so the ref will be invalid. In the normal React flow children get mounted before their parents, but this circumvents that by mounting the parents first and then the children, which prevents any access to those children during the mounting cycle of their parents. That puts limitations on the reusability of such a component, and has the potential to cause subtle problems that can be difficult to find and debug.

Comment: @Spencer You're right. I left that way, and after some days I encountered that exact issue you're describing (a focus on componentDidMount)... I ended up reverting the change and enabling it under a dedicated optional prop of my portal component... Meh, but stil...